# How do I access the value of the parent class in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

So I have two models here

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_type

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to="products")
    product_price = models.FloatField()
    product_description = models.TextField(default="Product Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

And I have created an api using django-rest-framework to be consumed by the React frontend. However, when I try to get the product_type, it'd just give me a number instead of the name as shown below. So, how can I replace that when retrieving the data with Product.objects.all() in the view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only show `product_type` instead of `id` you can use `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` in your `ProductSerializer` and with defining `source` in that method you can tell serializer to return your desired field.

Example:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='product_type__product_type')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_name', 'product_image',  'product_price', 'product_description', 'product_type')
```

But if you want to serialize all the `ProductType` itself you can define a serializer for this model and then use this serializer in your `ProductSerializer` to serialize the whole object of `ProductType`.

Example:

```
class ProductTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductType
        fields = ('id', 'product_type',)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_type = ProductTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_name', 'product_image',  'product_price', 'product_description', 'product_type')
```

The second solution is also known as `nested serializers`.

Comment: The second solution gave me the same result and the first one threw an attribute error. However, I got to solve it by referring the documentation. I thought the problem exists within the views, but not the serializers. Anyways, thank you.